# How to show that addition is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f: R \times R \rightarrow R$ and let the metric over $R$ be $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and let the metric in $R \times R$ be $d_2((x,y),(a,b))= ((x-y)^2+(a-b)^2)^{1/2}$.

I believe I understand how to proceed to prove these types of things, in general, but I am having trouble with this one.

It needs to be shown that for any $c=(a,b)$ in $R \times R$ and all $ \epsilon >0 $ there exists a $\delta$ such that for all $z=(x,y)$, $d_2(c,z) < \delta$ implies $d(b+a, x+y) < \epsilon$.

I know I should find that $|x+y-a-b| < ... < f( \delta , a,b)$ at which point I can choose $\delta$ to be sufficiently small to find $|x+y-a-b| < \epsilon$.

But I am having a difficult time using $d_2(z,c) < \delta$ to get something I can substitute in for the other inequality.

Could you help get me started?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: If $d_2((x,y),(a,b))<\delta$, then $|x-a|$ and $|x-b|$ are both less than $\delta$.

Comment: Your notations are off: if $z=(x,y)$, then how do you manage to add $y+z$?

Comment: Did you mean $d_2((x,y),(a,b))= ((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)^{1/2}$?

Comment: I think it is correct now. The metric is certainly correct as it is -- it's what makes the problem so annoying.

Comment: Meelo, I am not understanding your hint. Say we choose (x,y)=(10^6, 1+10^6) and (a,b)=(0,0). Then we have $d_2=1<2.$ But this does not gives us that $|10^6-1| < 2$.